# Starting Sessions in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, syntax-error

**starting at the top of the view:**

```
<?php ### CREATE SESSION **
$this->load->library('session'); $this->load->library('encrypt');

$newdata = array(
'session_id'  => random hash,
'ip_address'    => 'string - user IP address',
'user_agent'    => 'string - user agent data',
'last_activity' => timestamp
);

$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');

?>
```

**Getting this error:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')'  on line 5
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: Is this your real code? Did you forget that variables start with `$`?

Comment: It's not updated. By the way, this stuff doesn't belong in a view file.

Comment: This has nothing to do with sessions, or code igniter. Its just a syntax error, and you news to learn to recognize simple things like that before posting for help.

Comment: Should this part `'string - user IP address'` be a php call to get the REMOTE_ADDR ? Sorry, was following: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html , its what they did

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this anyways? The citation in the user guide is nothing more than an explanation of what data CI uses internally when it saves a session to the database.

Comment: Just to create a session and store even just an IP address in the session data.. to start

Comment: that data is by default is in the session. you dont need to randomly set that data.

Comment: Its not storing it in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your new comments, to start a session all you need to do is:

```
<?php
   //Start session
   $this->load->library('session');

   //Try retriving data:
   $session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
   echo $session_id;
```

Comment: That's a good start, which... i already have. I'm trying to OUTPUT that session data (just to check)..

Comment: I have this in my app/config/config.php: `$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'thetable';
$config['sess_match_ip']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;`

Comment: The problem is, it isnt sending it to my database. I still have 0 rows.

Comment: When I access the page. Sorry for the multiple replies.

Comment: Updated my answer. Try using that without the database first to see that sessions is working. Then we will work on using a database as a backend.

Comment: This code: $this->load->library('session'); $this->load->library('encrypt');

$newdata = array(
'session_id'  => random hash,
'ip_address'    => 'string - user IP address',
'user_agent'    => 'string - user agent data',
'last_activity' => timestamp
);

$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
   echo $session_id;  *gives errror* : `syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')' in on line 5`